# Building search REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm using a gem called `gem 'open_taobao'`

The following is how i get my data in `json`

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  layout 'layouts/frontend_base'

  def index
    @searchterm = "basketball"
    @search = OpenTaobao.get(
      :method => "taobao.tbk.item.get",
      :fields => "num_iid,title,nick,pict_url,cid,price,type,delist_time,post_fee,score,volume",
      :q => @searchterm,
      :page_size => 1,
      :sort => "_des",
    )
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do from my view is have a input field with submit and whatever is in the input box will replace my query variable below

`:q => @searchterm`

What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your form like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_path do %>
  <%= input_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

in your controller, you shouldn't need to set another instance variable `@searchterm`

You could do:

```
def index
    @search = OpenTaobao.get(
      :method => "taobao.tbk.item.get",
      :fields => "num_iid,title,nick,pict_url,cid,price,type,delist_time,post_fee,score,volume",
      :q => params[:q],
      :page_size => 1,
      :sort => "_des",
    )
    # what you do depends on the data type returned here. if it's a JSON string, you should parse it and reassign to @search, if not you may not need to do anything
  end
```

In your view,

```
#search/index.html.erb
<% @search.each do |result_key, result_value| %>
  # you can deal with the html here
  <%= result_key %>
  <%= result_value %>
<% end %>
```